# Why do I get a 500 Internal Server Error after creating an annotation using a http request on an html web resource in Dynamics 365?

Tags: javascript, html, httpwebrequest, dynamics-365

Users are looking to create Notes(annotations) from a tab with a custom Notes View created with html and javascript.  I've added the following code to the resource, and though the note is created and the incident is linked as desired, The web resource returns a 500 internal server error on the form.

Here is the added code:

```
    <script>
        function addNewNote(title_b, notetext_b) {
            debugger;
            caseId = getUrlParam("id");
            console.log("Case ID: " + caseId);
            console.log("Title: " + title_b);
            console.log("NoteText: " + notetext_b);
            var entity = {};
            entity["objectid_incident@odata.bind"] = "/incidents(" + caseId + ")";
            entity["subject"] = title_b;
            entity["notetext"] = notetext_b;

            var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
            req.open("POST", parent.Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl() + "/api/data/v9.0/annotations", true);
            req.setRequestHeader("OData-MaxVersion", "4.0");
            req.setRequestHeader("OData-Version", "4.0");
            req.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
            req.onreadystatechange = function () {
                debugger;
                if (this.readyState === 4) {
                    req.onreadystatechange = null;
                    if (this.status === 204) {
                        var uri = this.getResponseHeader("OData-EntityId");
                        var regExp = /\(([^)]+)\)/;
                        var matches = regExp.exec(uri);
                        var newEntityId = matches[1];
                    } else {
                        parent.Xrm.Utility.alertDialog(this.statusText);
                    }
                }
            };
            req.send(JSON.stringify(entity));
            parent.Xrm.Page.getControl("WebResource_NotesTabView").refresh();
        }

    </script>
    <form action="" method="get" class="form-newnote">
        <div class="form-newnote">
            <label for="sub">Title </label>
            <input type="text" size="114" name="sub" id="sub" required="true">
        </div>
        <div class="form-newnote">
            <label for="notetext">Note </label>
            <textarea name="notetext" rows="4" cols="114" id="notetext"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="form-newnote">
            <button onclick="addNewNote(sub.value, notetext.value)">Add Note</button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Before clicking "Add Note":
[before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/08z7Q.png)

After clicking "Add Note":
[after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J1SQ7.png)

Keep in mind that the note is successful created and linked to the case.

Comment: do you have access to the servers logs? Might be something helpful there.

Comment: did you managed to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I could sense 2-3 issues.

1. this.status I think here you should debug, might be you will have return as 200 rather than 204.
2. You are calling webapi asynchronous, it should not be an issue but try calling it synchronous.
3. If you say notes are been created log tracing in console and check till which point your code reaches.